# Why does \expandafter not expand the full { } group?

Tags: expansion

I thought I had understood the principle of expansion ... but apparently not!

```
\def\a{AAA}
\def\b{BBB}   

\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\a\b}
```

I thought that the 2 `\expandafter` would store `\detokenize` and `{}` resp. and then expand `\a` into `AAA` and `\b` into `BBB`. Therefore after one round of expansion, we would 
have:

```
\detokenize{AAABBB}
```

and thus the output should be simply "AAABBB". But it is not the case. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Question titles must summaries the question. Please avoid titles which would fit 1000 largely different questions.

Comment: `\expandafter` jumps over *one* token, expands *once* the following one (if it's expandable, otherwise nothing happens) and vanishes.

Comment: You might be looking for `\expandnext` from `etextools`, which in your case could be used as `\expandnext\detokenize\a\b`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\expandafter` stores exactly one token. So the expansion order is `\expandafter`-`\expandafter`-`\a`.

After this everything is restored and `\detokenize` is executed.

This is the reason why you sometimes see crazy successions of `\expandafter`: To reverse the expansion order of *n* tokens you basically need *2^n-1* `\expandafter`s. At least you don't need `\expandafter` before `\detokenize` because it will initiate expansion looking for its argument.

So

```
\detokenize\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\a\b}
```

gives the expansion order you need: `\expandafter`-`\expandafter`-`\expandafter`-`\b`. After restoring there is

```
\detokenize\expandafter{\a BBB}
```

finally yielding the desired output.

In case your're interested in always fully expanding the contents of `{}` (whatever they are), you can't (in general). Depending on a concrete context, there may be alternatives. So if this answer is not what you were looking for, please elaborate.

Comment: I've found [Stephan Bechtolsheim's TUGboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb09-1/tb20bechtolsheim.pdf) to be helpful on this topic, maybe you could include it as a reference showing more examples. (@nicolasroy)